# Add fields to comment section on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments, field

I'm building a very simple site on wordpress.com and would like to know how to add fields to my comments. I'm not building it from scratch, I'm using one of the free existing themes. Can I do that? Do you guys know of any plugins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you are looking after is somewhat this: 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-comments-form-in-wordpress/